# How to track email in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using rails 4.0 and I want to know how to get email tracking.

I mean I want to know how many users open my email and when they opened, if it is deleted or not, if it were read.

In short, I want to know how to track email related information after they are successfully delivered.

Comment: Try placing a pixel in email template that goes through your application route, whenever someone opens your mail, pixel will be downloaded and you can easily increase its counter to know how many times your mail has been opened, to make it more feature rich, append unique ids of users and then track them. You can't track if an email has been deleted or not if it is not opened.

Comment: The only way you *could* do this is by including an image in your email and tracking the requests to the image on your server with analytics, but most of the time now, google servers will download the image ahead of time, or it will be blocked by the client.

Comment: there is a gem for this, haven't tested it though: https://github.com/ankane/ahoy_email

Comment: The way I implement email metrics is by using a third party solution such as SendGrid. Not sure if you want to have a home built solution but SendGrid does allow you to do what you are looking for, it allows to track deliveries, opened emails, clicks, bounces, spam reports etc.

Comment: I think the variation in the ideas that have been offered in comments show that this question is too broad for this format.  Hopefully those comments will give you some ideas to try, and when you get more specific questions you can ask them here.

Answer (score 4):

I'll give you an example how I implemented this feature:

1. My `CustomMailer` class generates a google tracking url similar to:

[http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid= Tracking ID&cid=Customer ID&t=Event hit type&ec=Event Category&ea=Event Action&el=Event Label&cs=Campaign Source&cm=Campaign Medium&cn=Campaign Name](https://www.formget.com/email-tracking-google-analytics/)

`@google_analytics_url = url`

2. My `CustomMailView` adds this link to an image (pixel image)

   `<img src=<%= @google_analytics_url %> width=1 height=1 />`

[More general info about different google analytics parameters](https://www.formget.com/email-tracking-google-analytics/)

**Full example using** [rails official docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html):

Mailer:

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @google_analytics_url  = 'http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-****&cid=CustomerID&t=event&ec=open_email&ea=Event Action&el=Event Label&cs=Campaign Source&cm=Campaign Medium&cn=Campaign Name'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

View mail_view.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Welcome to example.com, <%= @user.name %></h1>
    <p>
      You have successfully signed up to example.com,
      your username is: <%= @user.login %>.<br>
    </p>
    <p>
      To login to the site, just follow this link: <%= @url %>.
    </p>
    <p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
    <img src=<%= @google_analytics_url %> width=1 height=1 />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @max_pleaner suggested, you can use that gem or go through one of this post - https://myles.eftos.id.au/blog/2013/08/25/track-email-opens-using-a-pixel-tracker-from-rails/#.V7XSSbMvDDd

What you are trying to embed is referred to as beacon-image or web bug

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer is useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could insert a pixel in it and track how many times its been downloaded. Just like an image. I can't write exact way, since I never tried it, but I am sure it could be done like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled a lot Here is the solution.

Firstly your mailer will look like this one

**UserMailer**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer


    default from: 'aniket.tiw@gmail.com'

    def send_mail(email,body ,subject,user)
        @body = body

        @user = user
        mail(to: email, subject: subject)
    end


end
```

Now let us create the routes

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/trackemail/:id', to: 'users#track_email'

end
```

Now before going to the view. You have to install Localtunnel so that whenever someone opens the email so it may get redirect as Gmail doesn't know localhost

I have attached the link [link](https://rubyplus.com/articles/4191-How-to-Expose-Local-Rails-App-to-the-Public-Internet) how to install localtunnel.

As you can see in my view I have also attached random string.This I have done because for the first time this method will work but then Gmail caches our record.So every time the URL should be new and the image gets open.Even you can hide the image by giving style

**user_mailer/send_mail.html.erb**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />

  </head>
  <body >
    <h1>Hi  </h1>
    <p>
      <%= @body %>

       <% str = (0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join %>
      <img src=<%="https://morwhnykzf.localtunnel.me/#{@user.id}?#{str} "%> class="profile" />
    </p>

  </body>
</html>
```

**users_controller**

```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
     def track_email
        send_file("/home/aniketshivamtiwari/Desktop/track.jpg",:disposition => true,:type=> 'image/jpeg',:x_sendfile => true)

      end

end
```